# Limit number of widgets based on available space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My widget tree looks like this :

```
Container(
   child : Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      spacing: 8,
      children: _getWidgets(),
   )
)
```

Now, this container is inside a column with other containers and therefore has a dynamic height based on the phone.

The `_getWidgets()` also returns a dynamic number of widgets. So, if the number of widgets exceed a certain limit, it overflows (easily fixable by enabling scroll).

What I want is to show only the number of widgets that fit in the given space without enabling scroll. Is this possible ?

For example, if I have 7 widgets, I calculate it will start overflowing at the 5th position, hence I only render 4 widgets.

Comment: Have you attempted to use a [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to get the height of the device and based on that value define how many widgets are shown?

Comment: @Eugene won't there be a possibility that some clipped widgets will be show at the bottom

Comment: @JoãoSoares I will look into MediaQuery. I was trying to do it with a LayoutBuilder but no success